# Can I create (add) a method override at runtime for a child class (reflection/emit?) in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a child class that does not override one of it's parent's base methods.  I want to create that override at runtime.  Can I do that?  I know it's possible to modify a method that already exists, but this is slightly different.

Suppose I have:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
  public bool testMethod() {
    return false;
  }
}

class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
}

...
MyBaseClass p=new MyBaseClas();
MyChildClass child=new MyChildClass();

p.testMethod();      // should always return false
child.testMethod();  // returns false

....  // Do Magic?

// Make child.testMethod(); return true
```

If MyChildClass had created an override of testMethod(), I could use Reflection;

```
// If
class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
  public override bool testMethod() {
    return false;
  }
}
// then I could have
MethodInfo m = typeof(MyChildClass).GetMethod("testMethod");
// and then do reflection stuff to change it
```

But m is null.

Can I make it so whenever a MyChildClass instance calls testMethod(), it returns true?

Comment: Why would you want to do this at runtime?

Comment: While there are odd cases where you must do something like this, 99.9999% of code should just be written "normally" and not constructed at runtime.

Comment: This sounds like an unwise idea that will lead to certain peril.

Comment: Do you control the source code of the derived class, and is the method of the base class declared `virtual`? It is straightforward to do so if both of those are true; it is very difficult otherwise.

Comment: Also, I strongly encourage you to use the conventions of C# when writing C#, not the conventions of Java, *particularly* where virtual methods are concerned.  Start your methods with a capital letter, be clear about which ones are virtual and which ones are not, and so on.

Comment: I want to do this at runtime because I cannot storm the offices of the developer and force them to mark their methods virtual at gunpoint, recompile all their code, and send it out to everyone?  I mean, it would be terribly impolite after they have worked so hard to create a helpful modding community.

Snarkiness aside, I want to do this because I don't control the base class.  If I could, I'd mark it virtual, the fields I want access to protected, wouldn't use Reflection, etc.  In the modding community, I suspect the odd case is where you don't have to worry about this sort of thing.

Comment: The problem is as stated, no "virtual" in the base function ;_;

I will risk the certain peril, btw!

Comment: I don't suppose anyone can add the tag "#deep-magic" for this question?

Answer (score 0):

To modify the behavior of a derived class at runtime you should build that in as a feature of the class:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
  public virtual bool TestMethod() => false; // MUST BE VIRTUAL
}

class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
  public MyChildClass()
  {
    implementation = () => base.TestMethod();
  }
  private Func<bool> implementation = null;
  public override bool TestMethod() => this.implementation();
  public void SetImplementation(Func<bool> f) => this.implementation = f;
}
```

And now you can make a new `MyChildClass` and call `SetImplementation(()=>true);` to change the behaviour of the class.

Comment: As noted, "I have a child class that does not override one of it's parent's base methods."

Are you saying it cannot be done?